# What is the origin / meaning of the icon used for "database"?

Tags: icons

I've never really understood what this icon, that looks like an oil drum

[image: Database icon, from The Noun Project]

and is commonly used to refer to a database, is actually supposed to represent.

What is it?

As a matter of fact, I've been searching for any kind of reading material about the history of the symbols commonly used in web app icons and haven't come up with anything helpful or interesting. Is there a good resource to read up on that?

Comment: three cans of chewing tobacco, alas not seen in workplaces anymore due to the tobacco-free laws. It means: you have to stay up late to fix the problems with the database, and you are not allowed to smoke in the machine room.

Comment: Answered on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822650/why-is-a-database-always-represented-with-a-cylinder

Comment: Maybe change your Accept checkmark to the actual answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**It is a picture of a "disk pack"** which is a stack of platters (usually 14 inch diameter) in a removable set. The original hard drives were the size of a washing machine, and had these swap-able packs. They had a clear plastic cover with a handle in the center, much like a cake carrier. You plopped it on to the drive, turned the handle to remove the cover, and then closed a door over the pack to enable the drive.

Amazing that people no longer know what they looked like. I made a clock where the dial was one of these big platters on which the head had crashed, leaving concentric marks in the orange surface (iron oxide). Of course, I had to be different, so I used a 168 hour motor and the "clock" showed the days of the week. Those synchronous motors are probably long gone also. They used to run all the stop lights.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note distinction between "drive" and "disks" (platters). They didn't used to be one item, as today. The drive was a standalone unit, a motor and control mechanisms that spun platters & moved arms. In the 1970s when this icon started being used to represent databases in IS, (micro)computers lacked fixed secondary storage, and ran off main memory and temporary (floppy) storage. Mainframes, OTOH, were the go-to for any _real_ computing, and had these large _precursors_ to modern hard disks. Approximated as the physical incarnation of the DB; software was often bespoke before standardisation.

Answer (score 6):

It represents a stack of hard disks.  For example, [from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Icons):

*"RAID diagram icon symbolizing the array of disks"*

[image]

Yes, this is talking about hard disks but the basic concept is the same.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not clear on what/why it is what it is, but at least I get there's some kind of real world thing being referred to.

Comment: Nothing to do with RAID. The depiction goes way further back than the emergence of RAID. Well back into at least the early eighties of last century and probably even further.

Comment: @MarjanVenema yeah I know but it was the most relevant visual I could find that made the point

Comment: Answer by a younger person who doesn't remember the original context. See user67695's answer, below, which I've edited to include pictures. See [this image](https://regmedia.co.uk/2016/04/28/vintage_disk_platters.jpg?x=442&y=293&crop=1), or google "database stack platters".

Answer (score 3):

Historical reasons. It's just a simplified depiction of an actual hard disk. Remember that a single hard drive is actually made up of a stack of flat disks with the read/write heads in between the disks. A simpler depiction would be just a cylinder without the horizontal bands.

Answer (score 0):

The American National Standards Institute (ANSI) set the standards for flowchart symbols in the 1960s - pre-dating hard disk drives. The standard memory in use at that time was drum memory - a precursor to disk drives - they were large metal cylinders coated in ferromagnetic recording material.

Comment: what makes you think that iconography follows ANSI standards? Most designers in Internet era didn't (don't) even know drum memory. I started in 1997 and never saw a drum memory!!

Answer (score 0):

It’s a stack of platters that would be loaded into the drive mechanism. (Drums were represented by a horizontal cylinder.) The symbol dates from a ‘new’ 1969 ISO standard for flow chart symbols.[IBM flowchart template 1969](https://web.archive.org/web/20120402204237/http://www.fh-jena.de/%7Ekleine/history/software/IBM-FlowchartingTechniques-GC20-8152-1.pdf) In those days, through probably the new millennium, coding, business and system analysis were actually formal regimes when teams of people worked in parallel on projects and had to optimize limited resources.
This changed in the ‘internet’ era with developers writing minimally viable and buggy code that will get tested by end users and (hopefully) fixed in the next sprint.